# Как убрать автоматический вызов функций из массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Как убрать автоматический вызов функций из массива?

```
var figure = [rectangle(), circle(), ellipse(), triangle(), trapezoid()];
```

Comment: Не добавляй `()`. Ваш кэп

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно записать в массив переменные хранящие код, то нужно убрать операторные скобки. При твоей записи функции вызываются и в массив будут записаны результаты возвращаемые функциями.